# How to make a function which works with array of pointers as well as with array of structs?

Tags: c++

I have got a function which sorts incoming vector

```
std::vector<Item> SimpleSort(std::vector<Item>&& items) {
   
   std::sort(items.begin(), items.end(), 
      [](const auto& left,const auto& right) { return left.id > right.id; }
   );

   return std::move(items); 
}
```

Also, I have got a second vector defined as:

`std::vector<const Item*> items;`

My goal is to make some function that can works with both types of vector.

I think I can do something like this:

```
template<typename ItemType>
std::vector<ItemType> SimpleSort(std::vector<ItemType>&& items) {
   if(std::is_pointer_v<ItemType>) {
      std::sort(items.begin(), items.end(), 
      [](const auto left,const auto right) { return left->id > right->id; });
   } else {
      std::sort(items.begin(), items.end(), 
      [](const auto& left,const auto& right) { return left.id > right.id; });
   }
   return std::move(items);
}
```

It is not that I want, because I don't want to copy logic, so overriding of that function is not suitable too. Is there any way to make it better than I offered?

Comment: Do you want to return vector of pointers if `ItemType` is a pointer?

Comment: Also, do you want to sort the input vector, or do you want to return a sorted copy of it?  The code is currently rather muddled in that department.

Comment: return type of the second function is wrong, should be `std::vector<ItemType>`. The `if` can be a `if constexpr`.

Comment: I want to recieve vector, sort him and return back. It is the same as 
```template <typename ItemType>
void SimpleSort(std::vector<ItemType>& items)```

Comment: In that case, your declaration should read `void SimpleSort(std::vector<ItemType>& items)`.  No need to move or return anything, just sort the vector passed in (passed by reference, note).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be a really good use-case for [`std::invoke()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/invoke) with a pointer to data member.
`std::invoke` will automatically take care of unwrapping the object parameter (you can pass it a reference, a pointer, or a `std::reference_wrapper<T>` and it'll automatically do the right thing)

Example: [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/WMrjo9ds9)

```cpp
template<class ItemType>
void SimpleSort(std::vector<ItemType>& items) {
    using Type = std::decay_t<std::remove_pointer_t<std::unwrap_ref_decay_t<ItemType>>>;

    std::sort(
        items.begin(),
        items.end(),
        [](auto const& lhs, auto const& rhs) {
            return
                std::invoke(&Type::id, lhs) >
                std::invoke(&Type::id, rhs);
        }
    );
}

// (1) can sort a vector of items
std::vector<Item> items = /*...*/;
SimpleSort(items);

// (2) can sort a vector of pointers to items
std::vector<Item*> items = /*...*/;
SimpleSort(items);

// (3) can sort a vector of reference_wrappers to items
std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<Item>> items = /*...*/;
SimpleSort(items);
```

---

An even easier option would be to use the new [`std::ranges::sort()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/ranges/sort) instead of `std::sort`.

The range variant allows you to pass a projection as the third parameter, which will be invoked with `std::invoke()`. (the result of this will then be compared with the comparator passed as the second argument)

So sorting a vector of items / pointers / reference wrappers is as easy as:

Example: [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/93sejPfvP)

```cpp
// (1) sort a vector of items
std::vector<Item> items = /*...*/;
std::ranges::sort(items, std::ranges::greater(), &Item::id);

// (2) sort a vector of pointers to items
std::vector<Item*> items = /*...*/;
std::ranges::sort(items, std::ranges::greater(), &Item::id);

// (3) sort a vector of reference_wrappers to items
std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<Item>> items = /*...*/;
std::ranges::sort(items, std::ranges::greater(), &Item::id);
```

Answer (score 3):

Just extract your sorting function to a named lambda (or a function if you will):

```
template<typename ItemType>
std::vector<ItemType> SimpleSort(std::vector<ItemType>&& items) {
   constexpr auto sorter = [](const auto& left,const auto& right) { return left.id > right.id; };

   if constexpr (std::is_pointer_v<ItemType>) { //note the constexpr here
      std::sort(items.begin(), items.end(), 
      [sorter](const auto& left,const auto& right) { return sorter(*left, *right); });
   } else {
      std::sort(items.begin(), items.end(), sorter);
   }
   return std::move(items);
}
```

`if constexpr` must be used, otherwise it will not compile unless `Item` has unary `operator*` overloaded.

Comment: Just a side note: such double function call to sorter function will be used for each comparison, which might be slower than desired

Comment: @AlexeyLarionov gcc optimises it out even at `-O1`, so it's not really a problem. And if the pointers are not from a single array, you've got much bigger overhead of cache misses that the overhead of calling an extra function.

Comment: Thanks you very much, i coded same solution some time ago but i forgot about constexpr